# Trigger : SOQL unable to fetch the record being committed

Tags: trigger

Objects involved A, B and C.

Scenario:

I'm inserting A record which in turn inserts B Record(Happen at after insert trigger of A).

Now Lets say B trigger insert C record (Off course after insert trigger of B ).

Now I have a look up on C record to A record and able to put it to C record lookup filed by passing as a parameter (Id of A record).

The challenge I'm facing here is at C trigger I have a map where I wish to build <Key = Id of A record and Value as A record.> => Here I'm querying for A record all required fields, But query returns null !.

Can someone please explain am I missing something in Order of Execution ? (A record is not yet committed to data base but since it's in after context Id is generated and Can't I query it until record is committed to database ?)

Thanks in advance.

Update:

This was failing because run as is being doing as guest user.

Comment: You should be able to query the values; if not, you're probably doing something wrong. However, we'd have to see some code in order to figure out what's going on. I realize the whole thing might be too complicated, but if you could include just the relevant code, that might help.

Comment: Hi sfdxfox thanks for confirmation, I will try to figure it out, just that wanted to confirm the possibility. It works fine in actual flow meaning when I insert a record from UI / Data loader ,but when inserting record A in the test class this scenario is failing at the point C trigger where the query for A is. fyi I was expecting you to confirm this first here :) thanks @sfdxfox as always.

Comment: @sfdxfox got the root cause this is cause the [salesforce update](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_user.htm#:~:text=Secure%20Object%20Permissions%20for%20Guest,or%20delete%20on%20specific%20objects.) : Guest User: New Guest User Access Setting and Removed Retired Permissions. (I'm running as runas guest user then it fails and if as sys admin user it works well)

Comment: That makes sense. This is the sort of thing that would have been useful to include in the question. I know it's sometimes hard to figure out what's relevant in a case like this, but I'd recommend mentioning the context (Communities, etc), as it can really help.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks you, sure I will keep questions neat and will do proper tagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to update the permissions:

Salesforce Spring ’20 Release:

[Guest User: New Guest User Access Setting and Removed Retired Permissions](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_user.htm#:%7E:text=Secure%20Object%20Permissions%20for%20Guest,or%20delete%20on%20specific%20objects.)